# javascript condition not working with sql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

If condition will work in else case also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var r=confirm("Do you want to Delete ?");
//alert(r);if (r==true){ alert("You pressed OK!"); document.write("<?php $conn = Yii::app()->db; ?>"); document.write("<?php $sql1 = "DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE c_id=$c_id"; ?>");
 document.write("<?php echo $sql1; ?>"); document.write("<?php $command=$conn->createCommand($sql1); ?>"); document.write("<?php $command->execute(); ?>");                             
}else { alert("You pressed Cancel!");history.go(-1); }
</script>
```

Comment: you will need to learn when each language is executed (php first, on the server, javascript after, in the client)

Comment: Javascript and php dont work like that. Also, you have commented out the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. You are generating PHP code from client-side JavaScript. The browser will just render it as (invalid) HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP commands:

```
$command=$conn->createCommand($sql1);  // This return "echo" command?

$command->execute(); // And this?
```

Try this:

```
document.write("<?=$sql1?>"); 
document.write("<?=($command=$conn->createCommand($sql1) ? 'SQL created with success!' : 'SQL fail')?>"); 
document.write("<?=($command->execute()?'SQL executed with success!' : 'SQL command fail')?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is meant for server side functions. javascript allows a page on client side to interact with the server in an easier way. The better way to accomplish what you are trying to do, would be to post to the php via javascript and let the php function handle the data and transactions.

This is very bad code practice. I will not go to particulars but really bad.

Here's more or less what it should/could look like ::

JQuery(much easier than javascript) ::

```
$(document).on('click',$('#someUniqueButtonID'),function(){
    var r = confirm('are you sure?');
    if(r){
        $.post(<?php echo #URL_for_controller/function ?>,#DATA_TO_SEND,function(status){
            alert('your Query was' + status);
            //What you want to do after                  
        });
    }
})
```

PHP ::

```
function Delete($id) {
    $sql1 = "DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE c_id=$id";
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql1)->execute();
    echo "Successful";
}
```

Not a perfect example but it will help with code readibility and much better code practice. as @user574632 mentioned. php and javascript dont work well like that. Many times we use php to get the url of an action, but the "work" should be done by php in a controller action.